# How to fix coding error after updating R?

Tags: r

I'm working with data of an animal's movements in the x,y,z direction in R 4.2.2.

**I'm getting this error:**

> Error in df[, seq(6, 125, 3)] : incorrect number of dimensions

This is the correct number of dimensions for my data. This code has previously worked perfectly before I updated R.

I tried deleting and redownloading R and Rstudio. I tried making sure all my program are update and in the right library.Any other ideas I could try?

I tried deleting and redownloading R and Rstudio. I tried making sure all my program are update and in the right library I've tried restarting and copying the code into a new file.Any other ideas I could try?

Comment: What does `dim(df)` give? Are you sure you loaded `df` properly? Have you looked at `head(df)` and `str(df)` to see if it looks right?

Comment: You could always use the old version of R, if that was working for you. Most R updates are side-by-side, so you probably don't even need to re-install the old version. But unless you can share some code and some sample input I don't think we can help further.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.